# edit the existing order administrative view

Tags: views, commerce

I am trying to edit the existing order administrative view of my drupal commerce store. What i want is, adding a new column which indicates the *sent status* of the PDF invoice.

What i have done so far: stored a value into database once email was send. Now i need to populate it in to order administrative view as a new column which shows the *sent status* of the each order.

Any help, or tips would be appreciated